# Avoid Echart adding dates in axis when using time type

Tags: javascript, charts, data-visualization, echarts

I'm using a echarts to create a basic chart that displays the count of "x" in some dates. When I'm using the `time` type in the axis, echarts "autocompletes" the missing dates in the interval:

[image]

So as a result I get some empty dates, is there anyway to avoid the axis doing this?

Here is the options I'm using:

```
         {
            dataset: {
              id: 'mydata',
              source: [
                {
                  "date": "2022-07-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 1
                },
                {
                  "date": "2022-05-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 15
                },
                {
                  "date": "2022-02-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 2
                },
                {
                  "date": "2022-01-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 1
                },
                {
                  "date": "2021-12-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 1
                },
                {
                  "date": "2021-11-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 2
                },
                {
                  "date": "2021-09-01T00:00:00Z",
                  "count": 2
                }
              ]
            },
            tooltip: {
              trigger: 'axis'
            },
            xAxis: {
              name: 'date',
              type: 'time',
              axisLabel: { formatter: "{MMM} {yyyy}" },
              splitLine: {
                show: false
              }
            },
            yAxis: { name: 'count', type: 'value' },
            series: [
              {
                type: 'bar',
                showBackground: true,
                encode: {
                  // Map the "date" column to X axis.
                  x: 'date',
                  // Map the "count" column to Y axis
                  y: 'count '
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

you can filter you data before add it to the chart

something like

```
const data = data.filter((obj) obj.count === 0)
```

options

```
{
            dataset: {
              id: 'mydata',
              source: data
            },
            tooltip: {
              trigger: 'axis'
            },
            xAxis: {
              name: 'date',
              type: 'time',
              axisLabel: { formatter: "{MMM} {yyyy}" },
              splitLine: {
                show: false
              }
            },
            yAxis: { name: 'count', type: 'value' },
            series: [
              {
                type: 'bar',
                showBackground: true,
                encode: {
                  // Map the "date" column to X axis.
                  x: 'date',
                  // Map the "count" column to Y axis
                  y: 'count '
                }
              }
            ]
          }
```